# Single-character Literals in Bison Parser

Tags: bison

I'm trying to make a parser in bison and it's giving me really weird compile errors when I use certain single-character terminals in the parser.

This works:

```
nonterminal1: 'a' nonterminal2 'b';
```

but this doesn't compile:

```
nonterminal1: '{' nonterminal2 '}';
```

Should I be escaping these characters somehow? I've tried quite a few Google searches and skimmed O'Reilly's flex & bison book but couldn't find anything about this.

Comment: What compile errors are you getting, and from where (C or bison?).

Answer (score 1):

Proof by counter-example:

```
%%
nonterminal1: 'a' nonterminal2 'b';
nonterminal1: '{' nonterminal2 '}';
nonterminal2: '.' | '!';
```

Bison compiles that without a complaint.  I tried 3 other variants of Yacc; all compiled it without complaint.  It also compiles without the a/b line.  I only tested as far as running `bison` on the file; I didn't test the C compiler on it, but it would be astonishing if the code produced by Bison was not valid.

The problem isn't as simple as what you've reduced it to.  So, please provide an actual SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) of what does not work for you, along with the error messages from Bison.  If there are options you're specifying to `bison`, tell us about those, too.  If the problem is compiling the output from `bison` (a C file) into an object file, you should state that too.

(For the record, the version of Bison was 2.3, running on Mac OS X 10.7.5.)

Note that if you are using certain non-programming editors, it is possible that the quote characters are being munged into something other than ASCII `'` (39; Unicode U+0027).  This would throw things off.  However, it is not clear why one line was munged and the other not.  You'd have to show us the error message for us to be able to help.